# MySQL Control Flow Advice (CASE/THEN)

Tags: mysql, if-statement, control-flow

I have a very peculiar problem on my hands. I have a project where the previous db engineer didn't gave a thought on db design and now im stuck with it. My question is simple:

I have two different select queries and one of them should be executed if a field is set or not, i.e.

if field1 is 0 -> execute query 1
if field1 is 1 -> execute query 2

So far i got here:

```
SELECT should_i_care
FROM 
    product_sample
WHERE
    pid='XXX'
CASE should_i_care
    WHEN '1' then call query2
    WHEN '0' then call query1
```

But found out that i cant declare the queries i want to run. Any suggestions?

Comment: this can't be a statement, it needs to be a script or procedure.  You'll need to use an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be a script or stored procedure like this

```
DECLARE  shouldICare INT; 

SELECT @shouldICare := should_i_care
FROM 
    product_sample
WHERE
    pid='XXX';

IF @shouldICare = 1 THEN
   Call query2;
ELSE
   Call query1;
END IF;
```

Comment: In the long run re-designing the table is the better choice, but thank you for this neat solution.